# Manage Custom permissions in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2016

my options for permissions are View, Add, Change, Delete, Administration, Development.

Is there an easy way to give a user View, Add, Change & Delete without adding them to each of those groups individually?

Comment: Create a custom Permission level with the permissions that you need, then create a group with this custom permission level then assign the users to it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with SP16 but for SP13 and O365 there is a Owner group that you should be able to add the user to. The Owner group will have all of those permissions for the site. If more permissions are needed there's the Site Collection Administration group.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to site settings->site permissions->permission levels->Add a permission level to create a custom permission level.

To View, Add, Change & Delete, you can select “Add Items”, “Edit Items”, “Delete Items”, “View Items” and other list permissions and site permissions you want to give the user.

Then grant this custom permission level to the relevant users.